# Loading TXT File with JQuery Load doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, file, load, txt

I am trying to split a large HTML-File into multiple HMTL files using JavaScript. W3Schools offers a great example of how to include files with JQuery Load:

https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_ajax_load

So I tried this out by copying the exact code into an html file and adding the txt-File "demo_test.txt" into the same folder. For some reason, nothing happens, when I click on the button.

I tried copying the code of the linked jquery file into a file jquery.js in the same folder and changing the 4th line to

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
```

But nothing changed.

JavaScript normally works on my computer, so there seems to be no problem. What can I do to make this work?

Comment: method `load()` works on the server. https://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: *The load() method loads data from a server and puts the returned data into the selected element*

Comment: Have you checked the developer tools of your browser? Seems like the file cannot be found. You can immediatley see that in the developer tools. What is the http header sent back from the server? Should be 200, found, but in you case I suspect it is 401 not found.

Comment: @Klaassiek Thanks a lot. Using the developer tools helped me find the error. It was a Cross-Origin Error. Since the text-file was stored on my local PC and the URL startet with "File" instead of "Https", Firefox blocked this for security reasons. But at the moment, I'm just using the Website offline. So I could just deactivate privacy.file_unique_origin in about:config of Firefox and now it works.

Comment: Browsers also have cross-origin extentions. You can use those to deliberately allow input from other sources while working on a localhost project. For example, for Firefox you could use this one: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/access-control-allow-origin/